# How to change the size of a component with effect when another component is rendered inside of it?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, user-experience

I have a modal component that overlays my page with a form to make some data inputs.

[image: modal with form box]

a second component is rendered next to the form when a certain condition is met (try to fetch data, render if anything is found).

When this happens I would like the whole card containing the two items to expand with some effect (horizontally if on desktop, vertically if on mobile), reducing smoothly the width of the first box during the transion.

[image: second component is added, changing the sizes of parent and brother]

I have tried to achieve this using a simple combination of the MUI Grid Container and Grid items,
but with this approach the second item always go on a new line or shows on the right but never changing the modal card overall size.

this is the style applied to the modal card:

```
sx={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: '50%',
                    left: '50%',
                    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    transitionDuration: '500ms',
                    minWidth: '30%'
                }}
```

So I thought of wrapping the 2 brothers in some DIV and apply some custom CSS taking advantage of the transitionDuration to apply an effect. But I couldn't make it work.

here is the style applied to the DIV that wraps the 2 brothers:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }}>
```

this is the div that contains the form grid container (1):

```
<div
                        style={{
                            flexGrow: 1,
                            minWidth: '30%',
                            transitionDuration: '500ms',
                            transitionTimingFunction: 'ease-out'
                        }}
                    >
```

and this is the div that contains the component to be shown when condition is met (2):

```
 <div
                            style={{
                                paddingLeft: 10,
                                transitionDuration: '500ms',
                                transitionTimingFunction: 'ease-in',
                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                minWidth: condition ? '200px' : '0%',
                                width: '0%'
                            }}
                        >
```

can anybody point me in the right direction?
I'm new to CSS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the data you can add a class (.active or something similar)to the parent container as well and add the styles you want to change like
`container.active > child{Blahblah styles}`